# how to execute three different task with serial time manner?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, threadpool

i need to execute three different task and each task should be execute like 1000ms , 2000ms, 3000ms.

can you tell me better way to implement and which is best of following 
1. Handler
2. Timertask
3. Thread
4. ExecutorServices and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AlarmManager to perform the operation:

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent.putExtra("Activity",1);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
manager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, pendingIntent);
alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent.putExtra("Activity",2);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
manager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000, pendingIntent);
alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent.putExtra("Activity",3);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
manager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 3000, pendingIntent);
```

**AlarmReceiver class**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        int extra = intent.getExtra("Activity");
        switch(extra) {
              case 1:
                     //start 1st activity

              case 2:
                     //start 2nd activity

              case 3:
                     //start 3rd activity
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It does not effect app's performance but it will wake up screen if screen goes to sleep. So if you do not have such requirement then you can use normal pending intent

Answer (score 1):

i am using handler for

Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }, 1000);

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }, 2000);
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }, 3000);
}
```